Container-type compatibility issues with older browsers
here we are using "container-type: size" to bind the paddings & font size to the size of the container, but this property container-type is not supported in browser versions older than 2022, due to which in many of the browsers and mobiles (including iphone X) the components UI is completely broken
how can i circumvent this issue, i do not want to do a complete rewrite as this property "container-type" is being used across my product at various places and a rewrite is not possible
  return (
    <div className="aspect-[614/315] w-full">
      <div className="group/card relative flex h-full w-full flex-col gap-[1.5cqw] [container-type:size]">
        <div className="relative flex h-[19.68%] w-full gap-[1cqw] rounded-[3.75cqw] bg-[#171717] p-[1cqw]">
          {aboutData.map((tab, index) => (
            <div key={tab.id} className="relative h-full min-w-0 flex-1">
              <button
                onClick={() => setActiveTab(tab.id)}
                className={`group relative flex h-full items-center justify-center rounded-full text-[3.3cqw] transition ${
                  activeTab === tab.id ? "text-white" : "text-[#aaa]"
                } w-full`}
                style={{ WebkitTapHighlightColor: "transparent" }}>
                <div className="absolute left-0 top-0 h-full w-0 rounded-[3cqw] bg-[#1D1D1D] transition-all duration-300 group-hover:w-full" />
                {aboutData.length > 1 && activeTab === tab.id && (
                  <motion.div
                    layoutId={`bubble-${groupNumber}`}
                    className="absolute h-full w-full rounded-[3cqw]"
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
                      boxShadow: `13.49px 16.87px 67.47px 8.43px #0A0A0A, -8.43px -16.87px 50.6px -16.87px #485B71`,
                    }}
                    transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0.2, duration: 0.6 }}
                  />
                )}
                {published ? (
                  <span className="relative z-10 max-w-full truncate border-none bg-transparent px-[5%] text-center text-white outline-none [font-size:inherit]">
                    {tab.label}
                  </span>
                ) : (
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={tab.label}
                    onChange={(e) => handleLabelChange(e, tab.id)}
                    className="relative z-10 border-none bg-transparent text-center text-white outline-none [font-size:inherit]"
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  />
                )}
              </button>
              {index !== 0 && !published && <CardActionButton onClick={() => deleteTab(tab.id)} />}
            </div>
          ))}
          {aboutData.length < 3 && !published && <AddButton onClick={addNewTab} toolTipTitle="Add Tab" />}
        </div>

        <div className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">{renderContent(aboutData)}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

